# Running wusa /uninstall /kb:5032007 /quiet /norestart error (CMD )

Tags: python, windows, winforms, patch, wuapi

while running this command as admin. uninstall kb is not happening, logging in eventID 8.

```
wusa /uninstall /kb:5032007 
/quiet /norestart
```

i have windows 11 with AMD64 machine.

if run without quiet and noreatart patch uninstallation will work.

i want to include this in python script. however uninstallation of kb number not working with /quiet /norestart.

if somebody helps, that would be gratefull.

i tried all possible way. but wusa not working

```
import subprocess

kb_number = "5032007"

command = f"wusa /uninstall /kb:{kb_number} /quiet /norestart"

try:
    result = subprocess.run(command, check=True, shell=True)
    print("Update uninstalled successfully.")
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
```

I would like to run wusa command in subprocess. And while uninstalling i would like to capture system event logs for the special task added in event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The `wusa` tool usage to quietly uninstall an update has been **deprecated**. The uninstall command with `/quiet` switch fails with event ID 8 in the Setup event log
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/deprecated-features

A powershell alternative can be:

```
Get-WindowsPackage -Online -PackageName "*KB5032007*" | 
  Remove-WindowsPackage -Online -NoRestart
```

Or with WU API (powershell example):

```
$KB = "5032007"

# List all installed updates. If you know the GUID already, you can skip to $KBU
$MUS = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session -pr @{ClientApplicationID="Script"}
$Searcher = $MUS.CreateUpdateSearcher()
$Results  = $Searcher.Search("IsInstalled=1")

# filter by KB number to get GUID
$GUID = ($Results.Updates | ? KBArticleIDs -Like $KB).Identity.UpdateID
$KBU  = $Searcher.Search("UpdateID='$GUID'")

# Uninstall update
$UC  = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl
$MUI = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Installer 
$UC.Add($KBU.Updates.Item(0))
$MUI.Updates = $UC
$MUI.Uninstall()
```

Note: a single update package can have multiple KBs, and multiple packages can reference the same KB

Comment: `Package Identity : Package_for_ServicingStack_2567~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~22621.2567.1.1`    i having Package Identity like this.  unable to identify right package by kb number.

Comment: @somesh Yes, you can run `Get-WindowsPackage -Online` to list the names of each installed package, and get the name from there. Not every update has the KB ID in the name

Comment: got it. Would you recommend any alternative way to uninstall update by kb number like 'pswindowsupdate'  I don't know pswindowsupdate how it will work on production.  I want to go with more pythonic way like win32 wuaapi agent. I would really appreciate if you recommend some other way to uninstall by kb number.

Comment: @somesh I've added an example of using the wua API with powershell - it should translate into pywin32 pretty closely, but I'm not familiar enough. Note that you need a GUID instead of a KB number. A KB is just a documentation reference, so multiple updates (usually for different OS like win10 vs 11) can share a single KB.

Comment: That said, you probably should not be regularly uninstalling windows updates, so I recommend finding a different approach to whatever issues you're solving with this

Comment: Thank you,  i will check that option using WUA API. i really appreciate you response.